# How to backup MySQL events with mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I'm using the following `mysqldump` command to backup ma database:

```
mysqldump --extended-insert=FALSE -hlocalhost -uusername -ppassword --databases my_database > ${FILELOCAL}
```

This is working very well.

I this database I also have some scheduled events.

Unfortunately the backup file doesn't contain my scheduled events.

**ATTENTION:** I don't want to know how to schedule a backup with `mysqldump`. I want to know how to also backup my scheduled events when using `mysqldump`.

Comment: Normal place to look would be [The MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/8.0/en/mysqldump-definition-data-dumps.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is just to add `--events` like this:

```
mysqldump --extended-insert=FALSE -hlocalhost -uusername -ppassword --databases my_database --events > ${FILELOCAL}
```